# Playing downloaded video data with AVPlayer?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, afnetworking, avplayer

I'm trying to download video from server, store it and then play it with `AVPlayer`. What I have so far is:

1. I use `AFNetworking` to download video data and I have it stored as `NSData` inside my `NSDictionary` of resources
2. I create my `TargetOverlayView` which is displaying resources content (images, text, playing audio and ...video - hopefully soon)
3. When it comes to show video I wrote method:

   ```
   (void)playVideo:(NSData*)video{
       NSLog(@"TargetOverlayView: playVideo");
       if (!video) {
           NSLog(@"TargetOV: nothing to play");
           [vPlayerLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
           vPlayerLayer = nil;
           vPlayer = nil;
           return;
       }
       //save nsdata into file
       NSLog(@"{SAVE} saving video data into file...");
       NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];            
       NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);             
       NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
       NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"video.3gp"]];
       [fileManager createFileAtPath:filePath contents:video attributes:nil];
       AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"]];
       vPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];//[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
       vPlayerLayer = [[AVPlayerLayer alloc] init];//[AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:vPlayer];
       vPlayerLayer.player = vPlayer;
       [vPlayerLayer setFrame:self.frame];
       [vPlayerLayer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor purpleColor] CGColor]];
       [self.layer addSublayer:vPlayerLayer];
       [vPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:NULL];
   }
   ```

I added also observer so I know when to play it:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
    if (vPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
        NSLog(@"video ready!");
        [vPlayer play];
    } else if (vPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
        NSLog(@"vide faield: %@", [vPlayer.error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

}

I wish I could just download mp4 and 3gp videos from server and play them, but only when I give this: http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8 Apple given link it works... I cannot manage to play downloaded 3gp data from `filepath` (is it possible at all to play 3gp or other formats?). Is there any way to play downloaded video? I don't need streaming (not roght now at least). Every help very appreciated.

EDIT:
I changed that bit about making file to:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"video.mp4"];
[video writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

and still not working...

EDIT2:
I typed in link to this file on server - then it worked (only works with mp4), but I need to download data and play vide from it, not just link to the resource...

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trying to download an HTTP live stream. Can you clarify? Normally you would just create the AVPlayerItem using the URL of the live stream, and not worry about downloading anything. That's kind of the point of a live stream.